# Migrate Existing Site to CMS like Drupal or Framework like Zend or Neither?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, content-management-system

I have an existing site (where nearly every line has been coded by hand) and I am considering adding functionality that I feel might be better managed by a CMS.  I stumbled across Drupal and from what I can tell, it seems to be flexible enough to handle my needs.

**How do I go about migrating my existing code/database to Drupal?**  I'm looking for a general process here; something that could be applied to a small site like a personal blog or a gigantic site like stackoverflow.com (obviously scaling issues arise, but I'm just looking for general considerations).

**Should I even bother?**  Should I instead consider switching to a framework (like Zend) which will provide me a little more structure moving forward? Or not migrate to anything at all.

FYI - My site is currently coded in `PHP` and `MySQL` with a little `jQuery` thrown in for good measure.

Comment: I would start learning more about a framework (like Zend) and after thoroughly understanding the framework start migrating your site. I personally don't like WordPress or any CMS like Drupal or Joomla etc.. as I find them extremely restricting (or at least inefficient for what I'm trying to accomplish with custom coding). So, it really depends on your project - I set up WordPress sites for clients who can barely navigate the internet to make changes to their site. All of my projects or bigger sites are all done with CodeIgniter.

Comment: I would strongly suggest any MVC like Zend or CodeIgnitor or whatever. Because cms like wordpress, drupal and joomla have their own restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your focus is content management, then stick with a CMS like Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla.

However if your application has a lot custom logic then go for a framework like Zend or Symfony which give you more control over the functionality than a CMS, which forces you into their programming model.

Comment: It would be appreciable for those down voting to leave a comment

Comment: Its unbelievably spineless of people to vote down logical sensible answers with no reason.

Answer (score 3):

Zend will take lot of time. Instead i suggest you to stick with Drupal or Wordpress (or search for the best matching CMS here: http://www.opensourcecms.com/.

If you still want to stick with Drupal then read this manual about site migration to drupal (below post you can find usefull links that will explain to you more about migrating site).
Here is the drupals manual http://drupal.org/documentation/migrate
The most known CMSs like Wordpress, Joomla or Drupal will always containt site migration information in their provided documentation, so you may also try to google it. ;)